# sed backreference: get each line and append it to end of line

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a file with following content:

```
$ cat -n w
     1  Smith   John    12345   jsmith
     2  Jones   Robert  23456   rjones
     3  Green   Ralph   34567   rgreen
     4  Brown   Fred    45678   fbrown
     5  Orange  Mabel   56789   morang
```

I want to get each line and then append at the end of that line the same text of that line.

Example I want this output:

```
$ cat -n w
     1  Smith   John    12345   jsmith  Smith   John    12345   jsmith
     2  Jones   Robert  23456   rjones  Jones   Robert  23456   rjones
     3  Green   Ralph   34567   rgreen  Green   Ralph   34567   rgreen
     4  Brown   Fred    45678   fbrown  Brown   Fred    45678   fbrown
     5  Orange  Mabel   56789   morange Orange  Mabel   56789   morange
```

I looked into sed command with backreferencing however I can't get it to work

```
$ sed 's/(.*)/\t\1/' wider
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Comment: `paste infile infile`

Comment: @don_crissti, sorry I can't upvote this comment more than once. Sweet and to the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` use [BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) by default, you need to escape `\(...\)` to capture the matching:

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/\(.*\)/\1\t\1/' <file
```

or using `-E` to enable [ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (which available in GNU sed and BSD sed, and will become standard soon), so you must not escape `(...)`:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -E 's/(.*)/\1\t\1/' <file
```

Setting locale to `C` help you match invalid unicode characters.

But, it's better job for `paste`:

```
paste file file
```

or `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "%s\t%s\n", $0, $0}' <file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)/\1\t\1/' <filename>
```

Comment: why escape \( \) brackets?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have anything against using awk, here is a way to do it :

```
awk '{print $0"\t"$0}'
```